# MOSFETs in parallel won't turn off

Tags: mosfet

I have connected three N channel MOSFETS in parallel (Nexperia PSMN1R2-25YLC) but when power is applied they conduct regardless of the gate voltage. The gates are just connected directly together and there is no capacitor to ground either. I have run out of components and need to understand this a bit better before ordering more. What might be causing them to conduct regardless of the gate voltage? The circuit being switched is at 24v and it doesn't need to switch quickly, this is just for powering up/down an external device - switching is likely to happen very infrequently (hours, days). I need it to support 24v at 5A = 120W with passive cooling, hence the parallel arrangement.

This is the current schematic: [image: current]

I've changed the schematic so the gates are separated with resistors and each has a stabilising capacitor. My question is whether this seems like a sane way to do it. The MOSFETS are logic level, the datasheet specifies a gate threshold voltage of about 1.2v, I'm giving it 3.3v. The circuit being switched is at 24v.

[image: proposed]

Comment: Maybe you have wired them incorrectly.

Comment: What voltage is measured at the gate, when the switch is supposed to be off?

Comment: How low does the gate voltage go?  If you don't get close to 0V relative to GND, the MOSFET may not turn off completely.

Comment: @Andyaka have checked the wiring umpteen times, pretty sure it's ok. Also, when I use a single mosfet it works correctly, wired the same way

Comment: @tangrs zero volts! in single mosfet configuration it switches off around 1 volt, fully on around 1.5

Comment: One or more of them may have suffered electrostatic damage causing drain-source leakage. Isolate each in turn to find the culprit.

Comment: sorry all, false alarm, I guess one or more of the fets was borked, dug up some other ones and tried in the same configuration and it works fine.

Comment: That mosfet has a Vdsmax of 25V, which is way too close to your 24V. The slightest PSU overshoot or inductive kick and you're out of spec. Also, that mosfet has a very low Rdson (although not officially guaranteed for 3.3V), I doubt you need three.

Comment: @marcelm thanks, yes, I've specced it up to a 30V one for the next go. At 3.3V Vgs it was very hot at 120W, over 100C and I need it to be barely warm with only passive cooling, 3 seemed about right.

Comment: @CharlieSkilbeck Honestly I'd go higher on the voltage. And the datasheet for your mosfet gives 2mΩ typical @ 3.3V, for 50mW dissipation. I wouldn't expect it to get very warm. You might want to double-check your Vgs when on, and measure the Vds and determine effective Rdson.